# MySQL query doesn't return anything or return wrong data

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. Table_1 have this fields.

```
table_1_id
name
image
adres
```

Table_2

```
table_2_id
name
email
phone
comment
datetime
need_id
```

I want to make when I click on the `ID_1` form `table_1` to load me all rows from `table_2` which have `table_1_id = 1`
I've tried with this query

```
SELECT t1*, t2.* FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2
                 WHERE t1.table_1_id = t2.need_id ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC
```

and show blank page. Then I tried like this

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table_1 t1
 JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.table_1_id = t2.need_id ORDER BY ` DateTime` DESC
```

This whatever I click is returned first 5 results from database and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `ID_1`, you don’t need to involve `table_1` in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2
WHERE need_id = ID_1 
ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC
```